# Google App Engine - MemcacheService - Will same instance be returned for a namespace?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I am using the following in my code to initialize a memcache service for a particular namespace.

```
MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService("NameSpace1");
```

I am not storing the MemcacheService instance anywhere. But the class in which I have this code is a singleton.

So, when I request for the MemcacheService instance again for the same namespace, I would get the same instance right? And it wouldn't disturb the cache entries I have added earlier, right?

Comment: you know you can test on your devserver without hitting production data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the same namespace in the same app, then you will be referencing the same cache entries.  It does not matter whether you are using the same MemcacheService or not, because the memcache storage is not on the same machine that your Java code is running.  You can think of the MemcacheService as a gateway through to the memcache storage backends, and you can have many gateways to the same storage.

In fact, in general your Java code could be running concurrently in multiple machines, in which case there would definitely be multiple instances of MemcacheService.